# What to assign to an x:DataType when using System.Linq.IGrouping

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, .net-standard-2.1

Ok, this should be something simple, but I'm stuck.

I'm upgrading an old .Net Xamarin project and one of the things that I wanted to do is to add x:DataType tags to the XAML files, so that it can validate and autocomplete all bindings. E.g.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.PageModels.Info"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyProject.Models"
             x:DataType="vm:InfoViewModel"
             x:Class="MyProject.Pages.Info.InfoPage"
             Title="PageTitle">
```

So far so good, but this particular page shows a grouped list of records, defined as:

```
public List<IGrouping<string, LocalDocument>> GroupedDocs { get; set; }
```

And now the compiler complains because I've not set a valid DataType to the ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate (because the bindings in the template do not exist in the ViewModel)... and I don't know what to assign to it, as it seems that x:DataType does not support Interfaces (and let's not even mention interfaces + generics).

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedDocs}" IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
                 Style="{StaticResource groupedList}" ItemTappedCommand="{Binding DocumentTappedCommand}">

        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="????"> <!-- <<<<< What to put here? -->
                <ViewCell Height="34">
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource groupHeader}">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Key}"
                               Style="{StaticResource groupHeaderText}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:LocalDocument">
                 <!-- (....) -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

**What should I specify instead of ???? on the previous code example?**

As a workaround, I've created a Dummy class that implements <IGrouping<string, Document> and assigned it as the x:DataType, but I don't really feel like that is a good solution. And, as I'm sure that many other projects will be using grouped lists, I'd be interested in knowing what the "best practice" would be for this case.

Comment: I could transform it, if that's what you mean, but it is the result of a Linq call that returns an IGrouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create your own Grouping.

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, LocalDocument>> GroupedDocs { get; set; }
```

Download the source file from the link below. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys

Comment: I like this solution! It still needs an extra C# class, just because, but the specified x:DataType and the property will be coherent (and the class might come handy in the future to add extra properties).

Answer (score 1):

Set the data type on the group header template as null: `x:DataType="{x:Null}"`

This will override the page level data type and bypass XAML compilation error about the binding on Key.  Hovering over Key still indicates *"Member not found in data context"* but it compiles fine, and grouping works as expected (Syncfusion listview in my case but generic listview should work the same way).